# angular 2 - display result of GET in console

Tags: angular

I have been amending the heroes tutorial and come across something that I do not understand so hopefully someone can help.

In HeroesComponent.ts is this snippet of code

```
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {

 heroes: Hero[];
 selectedHero: Hero;

  constructor(private router: Router, private heroService: HeroService) { }

 getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getHeroes();
  }

 onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
  this.selectedHero = hero;
 }
```

And this works - the hero names are displayed to the corresponding html.

But, in getHeroes(), if I add a console statement

```
getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
  console.log("heroes list is " + this.heroes)
  }
```

Then the browser console shows "heroes list is undefined", yet the array of hero is displayed in the html.

Why is heroes undefined?

Answer (score 0):

because console is synchronous and the get is async, the array is undefined